# c++ extension in php yii framework

Tags: php, c++, yii

I want to use C++ extension in yii. I have already compile .so file and successfully used in php script. But when I used it in yii framework, it occurs that "class not found",anyone knows why?

The C++ extension is `rdkafka.so` :  https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka

```
 $conf = new RdKafka\Conf();
 $conf->set("ssl.key.location","./conf/client.key");
 $conf->set("ssl.certificate.location","./conf/client.pem");
 $conf->set("ssl.ca.location","./conf/ca.pem");
 $conf->set("security.protocol","SSL");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running this code in a namespaced file, you need to either import the class, or prefix it with a `\`:

```
$conf = new \RdKafka\Conf();
```

Comment: I have resolved this issue,the reason is that the extension 'librdkafka.so' was not in the right path.Thanks